# Explain why the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-d)^2+\alpha|x|$ is strictly convex.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha>0$ be given.

(i) Explain why the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}(x-d)^2+\alpha|x|$ is strictly convex.

(ii) verify that 
\begin{equation}
\bar{x}=(|d|-\alpha)_{+}\;\text{sign(d)}=\begin{cases}
d+\alpha,\qquad\text{if }\;\;\;\;\;\;d<-\alpha\\
0,\qquad\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{if}\;\; -\alpha\leq d\leq \alpha\\
d-\alpha\qquad\;\;\text{if}\;\;\;\;\;\;\alpha<d
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is a minimizer of $f$ and therefore $\bar{x}$ is unique. (I believe $|d|-\alpha)_{+}\;\text{sign(d)}$ means we only care about positive values)

I am looking for confirmation that I am on the right path with this problem.

For part (i) I think it should follow as such:

1. Show $f$ has a minimum via differential calculus. That is, set $f'(x)=0$ and find the critical point.
2. Show that this minimum is unique
3. Show that $0\in\partial f(\bar{x})$ (i.e. Generalized Fermat theorem) which will give strict convexity

For part (ii), intuitively I want to simply substitute each case value into $f'(\bar{x})=0$, and show that it holds; however, it only seems to hold for the case where $d<-\alpha$.

Comment: Show the convexity just by definition. Or notice that both the quadratic and absolute value function themselves are strict convex.

Comment: For part (i), note that the sum of two convex functions will be convex.

Comment: Your $f$ is in fact strongly convex! The absolute value function is trivially convex. The quadratic part is strongly convex (recall definition). The sum of a convex function and a strongly convex function is again strongly convex. Finally, strong convexity is stronger than strict convexity.